# vue i18n custom pluralization not working as excepted

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

i'm trying to make custom pluralization for arabic language but pluralization length is stays at the 3 options olny

```
  "number": "0 | 1 | 2 | bigger than 2 and smaller than 10 | bigger than 10",
```

here if the number equals 0 it will retruns 0 if it equal 1 it will return 1 other than that it will return 2 not the other options

here is my code:

**ar.json file**

```
  "number": "0 | 1 | 2 | bigger than 2 and smaller than 10 | bigger than 10",
```

**pluralization.js file**

```
function arPluralization(choise, choicesLength) {
    if (choise === 0) {
        return 0
    }
    if (choise === 1) {
        return 1
    }
    if (choise === 2) {
        return 2
    }
    if (choise > 2 && choise < 11) {
        return 3
    }
    if (choise > 10) {
        return 4
    }
    return choicesLength === 4;
}

export default {
    'ar': arPluralization
}
```

**i18n/index.js file**

```
import en from './locales/en'
import ar from './locales/ar'
import arPluralization from "./rules/pluralization";

export default createI18n({
  locale: 'ar',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: { en, ar },
  pluralizationRules: arPluralization
})
```

** the componnent file **

```
    <h1>
      {{ $t("number", 10}}
     // if the number bigger than 2 it will return 2 even if the number bigger than 2 
    </h1>
```